# how to solve this npm glob-parent problem

Tags: javascript, npm

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: moderate
Regular expression denial of service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
```

I just install cookie-parser to cmd.
As mentioned above, there were 4 moderates.
My glob-parent -v is currently 7.19.1
It doesn't work 'npm audit' and 'npm audit fix'
How should I do?

Comment: Did you try npm-audit-fix like it says?

Comment: yes, I tried but it also doesn't worked

Answer (score 22):

In your package.json, add this target under scripts:

```
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
```

Then add this below the scripts:

```
"resolutions": {
   "glob-parent": "^6.0.1"
}
```

One thing, I don't know if any dependent packages that use an older version  will break because of 6.0.1.

Comment: Added ```"resolutions": { "glob-parent": "^6.0.1" }``` and execute ```yarn``` command solve my issue. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I do "npm install" being the first installation. If I remove `"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"` and run npm install then I get the "glob-parent" vulnerabilities. Then, I add `"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"` and run again "npm install" and the vulnerabilities disappear.

Comment: `npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "npx npm-force-resolutions" of package "preinstall@npx npm-force-resolutions": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`

Comment: According to the owner of another package that has this as a dep, v6.0.1 doesn't have support for 2019 NodeJs. https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1191#issuecomment-1009063719

Answer (score 18):

I'm the person who wrote [the fix for `glob-parent`](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-parent/commit/f9231168b0041fea3f8f954b3cceb56269fc6366) that landed in `glob-parent@5.1.2`. There are (at least) three ways to address this.

First possibility: Update from `watchpack` version 1 to `watchpack` version 2. `watchpack` version 2 does not depend on a vulnerable version of `glob-parent`. Unfortunately, there is no `CHANGELOG` file in the `watchpack` repository, so you'll have to find the relevant breaking changes some other way. Maybe if you have excellent test coverage, you can rely on that. Or if your project is relatively new, then simply building it with `watchpack` version 2 to begin with will be the way to go.

The second possibility is that if `watchpack` is a development dependency only and not something used by the user-facing part of your app, then you probably don't need to worry about this at all and can ignore the message. I don't recommend this, but I also have to admit that [`npm audit` warnings can be a little bit boy-crying-wolf sometimes](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/).

The third option is to patch your vulnerable `glob-parent` with [the fix](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-parent/commit/f9231168b0041fea3f8f954b3cceb56269fc6366). However, you have to know what your doing (particularly how `npm` works) to not shoot yourself in the foot and end up undoing the fix without realizing it. So this is also not something I recommend.

If you can update `watchpack` to 2.x, that is the way to go.

Comment: as per https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/
adding 
npm audit --production
shows that the error is only on dev mode which is false positive error

Comment: I'm getting the glob-parent error in the production as well.

Answer (score 18):

Use the following overrides and It will resolve the Issue

```
 "overrides": {
    "chokidar": "3.5.3",
    "glob-parent": "6.0.2"
  }
```

Add the above in your package.json and do `npm update`

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I found this to be very useful and worked well for my situation. Of course, anyone using this should be mindful of what you are overriding as there could always be some side effect or potentially break other parts of your build. But this definitely worked well for my situation. Thank you again!

Comment: that did for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just update chokidar deps for your project

```
npm install chokidar@latest --save-dev
```

If it doesn't help, you should update glob-parent to latest version.
Check version you have

```
npm list glob-parent
```

and update to latest

```
npm install glob-parent@latest
```