# moderate severity vulnerabilities with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I am developing a web application with Angular but I have a problem installing json server. Please help me correct this problem.

Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
node_modules/react-dev-utils
react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: moderate
Regular expression denial of service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
watchpack-chokidar2  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/watchpack
webpack  4.44.0 - 4.46.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack
webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.11.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack-dev-server
node_modules/webpack-dev-server
@angular-devkit/build-angular  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
@angular-devkit/build-webpack  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack
@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  0.3.1 - 0.5.0-beta.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/react-scripts

12 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaYWX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fClru.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning to let you know that there is some *known* vulnerabilities on the packages you using in your project.

*vulnerabilities* can be missbehavior, bugs, crashes, security vulnerabilities, etc...

`npm` keep tracks of known vulnerabilities of all the `npm` packages.
So basiacally you have to wait updates on your package to fix the vulnerability, you can also try to use a different version of the package, or use a different package.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of : [how to solve this npm glob-parent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333071/how-to-solve-this-npm-glob-parent-problem)
Answer:  ​https://stackoverflow.com/a/68342168/158649

As it is a dev dependency, not a big deal,

```
npm update glob-parent@5.1.2 --depth 4
```

has no effect on the npm audit message.

`npm audit` warnings can be a [little bit boy-crying-wolf sometimes](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/).

```
npm install glob-parent@5.1.2 --save-dev
```

does remove the warning but not really much to worry about.