# glob-parent with vulnerability does not fix

Tags: npm

I'm having a problem updating the glob-parent dependencies, I tried to run the `npm audit fix`, but it's not being enough. I've seen other posts about the resolution like adding a script or updating the `watchpack` version 2 - it's in the **version 2.3.1** - but none solved it, does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I followed this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333071/how-to-solve-this-npm-glob-parent-problem