# glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex

Tags: javascript, yarn-lock.json

I am trying to work on a vulnerability where I need to fix the glob-parent.

This is the dependant bot-message

```
The latest possible version that can be installed is 3.1.0 because of the following conflicting dependency

webpack-dev-server@3.11.2 requires glob-parent@3.1.0 via a transitive dependency on chokidar@2.1.8
```

I have checked some of the solutions on the internet [how to solve this npm glob-parent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333071/how-to-solve-this-npm-glob-parent-problem) but it didn't work out for me. I am not sure exactly how to fix this so any help is appreciated

package.json

```
"glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
```

**yarn.lock**

```
"chokidar@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0", chokidar@^3.4.1:
  version "3.5.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chokidar/-/chokidar-3.5.1.tgz#ee9ce7bbebd2b79f49f304799d5468e31e14e68a"
  integrity sha512-9+s+Od+W0VJJzawDma/gvBNQqkTiqYTWLuZoyAsivsI4AaWTCzHG06/TMjsf1cYe9Cb97UCEhjz7HvnPk2p/tw==
  dependencies:
    anymatch "~3.1.1"
    braces "~3.0.2"
    glob-parent "~5.1.0"
    is-binary-path "~2.1.0"
    is-glob "~4.0.1"
    normalize-path "~3.0.0"
    readdirp "~3.5.0"
  optionalDependencies:
    fsevents "~2.3.1"

chokidar@^2.1.8:
  version "2.1.8"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chokidar/-/chokidar-2.1.8.tgz#804b3a7b6a99358c3c5c61e71d8728f041cff917"
  integrity sha512-ZmZUazfOzf0Nve7duiCKD23PFSCs4JPoYyccjUFF3aQkQadqBhfzhjkwBH2mNOG9cTBwhamM37EIsIkZw3nRgg==
  dependencies:
    anymatch "^2.0.0"
    async-each "^1.0.1"
    braces "^2.3.2"
    glob-parent "^3.1.0"
    inherits "^2.0.3"
    is-binary-path "^1.0.0"
    is-glob "^4.0.0"
    normalize-path "^3.0.0"
    path-is-absolute "^1.0.0"
    readdirp "^2.2.1"
    upath "^1.1.1"
  optionalDependencies:
    fsevents "^1.2.7"

chokidar@^3.5.3:
  version "3.5.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/chokidar/-/chokidar-3.5.3.tgz#1cf37c8707b932bd1af1ae22c0432e2acd1903bd"
  integrity sha512-Dr3sfKRP6oTcjf2JmUmFJfeVMvXBdegxB0iVQ5eb2V10uFJUCAS8OByZdVAyVb8xXNz3GjjTgj9kLWsZTqE6kw==
  dependencies:
    anymatch "~3.1.2"
    braces "~3.0.2"
    glob-parent "~5.1.2"
    is-binary-path "~2.1.0"
    is-glob "~4.0.1"
    normalize-path "~3.0.0"
    readdirp "~3.6.0"
  optionalDependencies:
    fsevents "~2.3.2"

glob-parent@^3.1.0:
  version "3.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/glob-parent/-/glob-parent-3.1.0.tgz#9e6af6299d8d3bd2bd40430832bd113df906c5ae"
  integrity sha1-nmr2KZ2NO9K9QEMIMr0RPfkGxa4=
  dependencies:
    is-glob "^3.1.0"
    path-dirname "^1.0.0"

glob-parent@^5.0.0, glob-parent@^5.1.2, glob-parent@~5.1.0, glob-parent@~5.1.2:
  version "5.1.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/glob-parent/-/glob-parent-5.1.2.tgz#869832c58034fe68a4093c17dc15e8340d8401c4"
  integrity sha512-AOIgSQCepiJYwP3ARnGx+5VnTu2HBYdzbGP45eLw1vr3zB3vZLeyed1sC9hnbcOc9/SrMyM5RPQrkGz4aS9Zow==
  dependencies:
    is-glob "^4.0.1"

 sass@^1.32.11:
  version "1.32.13"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/sass/-/sass-1.32.13.tgz#8d29c849e625a415bce71609c7cf95e15f74ed00"
  integrity sha512-dEgI9nShraqP7cXQH+lEXVf73WOPCse0QlFzSD8k+1TcOxCMwVXfQlr0jtoluZysQOyJGnfr21dLvYKDJq8HkA==
  dependencies:
    chokidar ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

 watchpack-chokidar2@^2.0.1:
  version "2.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/watchpack-chokidar2/-/watchpack-chokidar2-2.0.1.tgz#38500072ee6ece66f3769936950ea1771be1c957"
  integrity sha512-nCFfBIPKr5Sh61s4LPpy1Wtfi0HE8isJ3d2Yb5/Ppw2P2B/3eVSEBjKfN0fmHJSK14+31KwMKmcrzs2GM4P0Ww==
  dependencies:
    chokidar "^2.1.8"

watchpack@^1.7.4:
  version "1.7.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/watchpack/-/watchpack-1.7.5.tgz#1267e6c55e0b9b5be44c2023aed5437a2c26c453"
  integrity sha512-9P3MWk6SrKjHsGkLT2KHXdQ/9SNkyoJbabxnKOoJepsvJjJG8uYTR3yTPxPQvNDI3w4Nz1xnE0TLHK4RIVe/MQ==
  dependencies:
    graceful-fs "^4.1.2"
    neo-async "^2.5.0"
  optionalDependencies:
    chokidar "^3.4.1"
    watchpack-chokidar2 "^2.0.1"

webpack-dev-server@^4.11.1:
  version "4.11.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-4.11.1.tgz#ae07f0d71ca0438cf88446f09029b92ce81380b5"
  integrity sha512-lILVz9tAUy1zGFwieuaQtYiadImb5M3d+H+L1zDYalYoDl0cksAB1UNyuE5MMWJrG6zR1tXkCP2fitl7yoUJiw==
  dependencies:
    "@types/bonjour" "^3.5.9"
    "@types/connect-history-api-fallback" "^1.3.5"
    "@types/express" "^4.17.13"
    "@types/serve-index" "^1.9.1"
    "@types/serve-static" "^1.13.10"
    "@types/sockjs" "^0.3.33"
    "@types/ws" "^8.5.1"
    ansi-html-community "^0.0.8"
    bonjour-service "^1.0.11"
    chokidar "^3.5.3"
    colorette "^2.0.10"
    compression "^1.7.4"
    connect-history-api-fallback "^2.0.0"
    default-gateway "^6.0.3"
    express "^4.17.3"
    graceful-fs "^4.2.6"
    html-entities "^2.3.2"
    http-proxy-middleware "^2.0.3"
    ipaddr.js "^2.0.1"
    open "^8.0.9"
    p-retry "^4.5.0"
    rimraf "^3.0.2"
    schema-utils "^4.0.0"
    selfsigned "^2.1.1"
    serve-index "^1.9.1"
    sockjs "^0.3.24"
    spdy "^4.0.2"
    webpack-dev-middleware "^5.3.1"
    ws "^8.4.2"


  version "7.26.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/eslint/-/eslint-7.26.0.tgz#d416fdcdcb3236cd8f282065312813f8c13982f6"
  integrity sha512-4R1ieRf52/izcZE7AlLy56uIHHDLT74Yzz2Iv2l6kDaYvEu9x+wMB5dZArVL8SYGXSYV2YAg70FcW5Y5nGGNIg==
  dependencies:
    "@babel/code-frame" "7.12.11"
    "@eslint/eslintrc" "^0.4.1"
    ajv "^6.10.0"
    chalk "^4.0.0"
    cross-spawn "^7.0.2"
    debug "^4.0.1"
    doctrine "^3.0.0"
    enquirer "^2.3.5"
    eslint-scope "^5.1.1"
    eslint-utils "^2.1.0"
    eslint-visitor-keys "^2.0.0"
    espree "^7.3.1"
    esquery "^1.4.0"
    esutils "^2.0.2"
    file-entry-cache "^6.0.1"
    functional-red-black-tree "^1.0.1"
    glob-parent "^5.0.0"
    globals "^13.6.0"
    ignore "^4.0.6"
    import-fresh "^3.0.0"
    imurmurhash "^0.1.4"
    is-glob "^4.0.0"
    js-yaml "^3.13.1"
    json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify "^1.0.1"
    levn "^0.4.1"
    lodash "^4.17.21"
    minimatch "^3.0.4"
    natural-compare "^1.4.0"
    optionator "^0.9.1"
    progress "^2.0.0"
    regexpp "^3.1.0"
    semver "^7.2.1"
    strip-ansi "^6.0.0"
    strip-json-comments "^3.1.0"
    table "^6.0.4"
    text-table "^0.2.0"
    v8-compile-cache "^2.0.3"
```

Comment: Did you tried to unistall glob-parent first (that's important) and then install it with the exact version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use this approach this worked for me. Not sure why it didn't worked in the first place

In your package.json, add this target under scripts:

```
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"

"resolutions": {
   "glob-parent": "^5.1.2"
}
```