# glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex

Tags: npm, npm-install

This stack overflow answer didn't work for me ([how to solve this npm glob-parent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333071/how-to-solve-this-npm-glob-parent-problem)).

Now the `blob-parent` needs to upgrade to version `6.0.1` or higher.

When I do `npm ls glob-parent`, this is what it looks.

[image]

Some of the `glob-parent` needs to be `6.0.1` or higher but `npm install glob-parent@6.0.1` won't upgrade all of `glob-parent`.

How can I upgrade the `glob-parent`? or how can I address `glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex` issue?

#### Attempts

I tried

`npm audit fix --force`

`npm install glob-parent`

`npm install glob-parent@6.0.1`

Answer (score 6):

After `npm install glob-parent@6.0.1`, if `"glob-parent": "^6.0.1"` is in your projects `package.json`; you can add a section below the dependency sections that contain the plugin depending on the lower version in `npm audit` called "overrides" like such:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
},  
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.13.10",
  "glob-parent": "^6.0.1"
},
"overrides": {
  "glob-parent": "$glob-parent"
}
```

> This will tell the plugin to use the local version of the dependency instead of the one specified in it's own package, but you may have to tinker with finding a version that all your plugins play along with.

This is because this happens based on the plugins `package.json` dependency. If they neglect to prefix the dependent version (such as `^6.0.1` for example) then they are telling any project importing them not to go above the version specified.. This could be because newer builds break the plugin, however it could have been accidental or simply because it has only been tested with versions up to the one it specifies. If the package has not been updated in a while, newer build may have resolved breaks from previous newer builds also though.

Edit: Also be sure the local dependency is in the same dependency group as the plugin relying on it.. for example.. if the dependency with the lower version is in `dependencies` and not `devDependencies`, then you should include the local version of the plugin you are overriding under `dependencies` as well.

Comment: this solution works for me and the explanation was clear about how this solution works. In my case, I need to do an extra step. I have to `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`. Then `npm i` to see the glob-parent updated.